# Buscar un input dentro de una tabla datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

estoy varios días con un problema el cual no se como solucionar verán tengo una formulario y dentro de el esta una tabla vacía que se llena luego de que el usuario ingrese a otro formulario y seleccione el ítem que desea el cual se mostrara en el primer formulario bien dentro de la fila que se creo se agregan dos inputs los cuales quiero agregar a bootstrapvalidator pero para ello primero debo buscar el input dentro de esta fila que se ha creado y obtener su atributo name mi código es el siguiente:

```
function RetornarArticulo(lista) {
var $tblrows = $("#DetalleArticulo tbody tr");
var arrArticulo = '';
$tblrows.each(function (index) {
    if (tDetalleArticulo.data().count() > 0) {
        var $tblrow = $(this);
        console.log($tblrow);
        let id_articulo = $tblrow.find("[id=id_articulo]").val();
        let codigo = $tblrow.find("[id=Codigo]").text();
        let descripcion = $tblrow.find("[id=descripcion]").text();
        let unidad = $tblrow.find("[id=Unidad]").text();
        let cantidad = $tblrow.find("[id=cantidad]").val();
        let cantidad_atendida = $tblrow.find("[id=cantidad_atendida]").val();
        let montoUnitario = $tblrow.find("[id=monto_unitario_mn]").val();
        let dato = id_articulo + '|' + codigo + '|' + descripcion + '|' + unidad + '|' + cantidad + '|' + cantidad_atendida + '|' + montoUnitario;
        if (arrArticulo === '') arrArticulo = dato;
        else arrArticulo = arrArticulo + '<@ARTICULO@>' + dato;
    }
});
$("#DatosArticulo").val(arrArticulo);
$("#ListaId").val(lista);
$("#EstadoForm").val('A');
//Luego de agregar el ítem del segundo formulario uso la función reload de datatable para mostrar lo seleccionado
 tDetalleArticulo.ajax.reload();

 //Esta variable tDetalleArticulo contiene a datatable cada vez que la ejecuto en consola me muestra 0
 tDetalleArticulo.rows().iterator('row', function (context, index) {
    let inputtable = $(this.row(index).node());
    console.log(inputtable);
 });

}
```

Luego de revisar que muestra en consola es 0 como si no viera la fila creada ayuda.
para un mayor entendimiento agrego mi html

```
<div class="table-resposive">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover m-t-0 m-b-0 table-main" id="DetalleArticulo">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center">Código</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center">Descripción</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center">Unidad</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center">Cantidad</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center">Precio Uni.</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center">Precio Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <label id="lblTotalFilas">Total Registros : 0</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <label>Sub Total</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label id="lblSubTotal">0.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <label>I.G.V</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label id="lblIGV">0.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <label>Monto Total</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label id="lblMontoTotal">0.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
<script src="~/Cube_Fast/js/validator/OrdenCompra.js"></script>
```

la funcion se encuentra dentro de ese script y es donde inicisializa datatable que es donde creo los inputs atraves de ajax aquí la configuración

```
tDetalleArticulo = $("#DetalleArticulo").DataTable({
    "bFilter": false,
    "searching": false,
    "sAutoWidth": false,
    "fixedHeader": {
        header: true
    },
    "sDom": 'Bfrtip',
    "language": {
        "processing": '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading..n.</span> ',
        "decimal": ".",
        "thousands": ","
    },
    "ajax": {
        "url": "AgregarArticulo",
        "type": "post",
        "data": function (d) {
            return {
                "listaId": $("#ListaId").val(),
                "datosArticulo": $("#DatosArticulo").val(),
                "idOrdenCompra": $("#id_orden_compra").val(),
                "EstadoForm": $("#EstadoForm").val(),
                "idMoneda": $("#id_moneda").val()
            };
        },
        "dataSrc": function (data) {
            switch (data.accion) {
                case "success":
                    let json = data.lista;
                    let conta = 0;
                    let row = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        row.push({
                            'IdArticulo': json[i].id_articulo,
                            'Codigo': json[i].Codigo,
                            'NombreArticulo': json[i].descripcion,
                            'UnidadCompraDes': json[i].UnidadCompraDes,
                            'Cantidad': json[i].cantidad,
                            'CantidadAtendida': json[i].cantidad_atendida,
                            'MontoUnitario': json[i].monto_unitario_mn,
                            'MontoTotal': json[i].monto_total_mn
                        });
                        ++conta;
                    }
                    $("#lblTotalFilas").text('Total Registros : ' + conta);
                    return row;
                case "error":
                    MostrarMensaje('Error de operación', data.Msj, 'error');
                    break;
            }
        },
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "className": 'text-nowrap',
            "targets": [0],
        }
    ],
    "columns":
    [
        {
            "width": "50px", "orderable": false,
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                console.log(full.CantidadAtendida);
                if (full.CantidadAtendida > 0) {
                    return '<input type="hidden" id="id_articulo" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].id_articulo" value="' + full.IdArticulo + '" />' + 
                            '<input type="hidden" id="cantidad_atendida" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].cantidad_atendida" value="' + full.CantidadAtendida + '" />';
                }
                else {
                    return '<a href="#" class="EliminarFila" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Eliminar">' +
                    '<i class="fa fa-eraser text-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
                    '<input type="hidden" id="id_articulo" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].id_articulo" value="' + full.IdArticulo + '" />';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false, "width": "100px",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<label id="Codigo" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].Codigo" >' + full.Codigo + '</label>';
            }
        },
        {
            "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false, "width": "200px",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<label id="descripcion" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].descripcion" >' + full.NombreArticulo + '</label>';
            }
        },
        {
            "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false, "width": "50px",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<label id="Unidad" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].UnidadCompraDes" >' + full.UnidadCompraDes + '</label>';
            }
        },
        {
            "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false, "width": "100px",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control csocdetalle" id="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].cantidad" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].cantidad" data-name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].cantidad" onchange="CalcularTotal()" value="' + full.Cantidad + '" />';
            }
        },
        {
            "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false, "width": "100px",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="monto_unitario_mn" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].monto_unitario_mn" onchange="CalcularTotal()" value="' + full.MontoUnitario + '" />';
            }
        },
        {
            "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false, "width": "100px",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<label id="monto_total_mn" name="CS_OC_DETALLE_LIST[' + meta.row + '].monto_total_mn" >' + full.MontoTotal + '</label>';
            }
        },
    ],
    "paging": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "sScrollX": true,
    "sSelect": true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El `$.each()` de jQuery recibe dos parametros, el primero es el indice que en tu caso seria la variable `index`, el segundo es el objeto por el cual se esta iterando.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
    "paging": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "sScrollX": true,
    "sSelect": true,
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
      tDetalleArticulo.rows().iterator('row', function (context, index) {
        let inputtable = $(this.row(index).node());
        console.log(inputtable);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder he probado tu código y nuevamente me retorna cero lo que quiero es obtener la fila que se crea para luego buscar el input que se ha creado dentro de esa fila

Comment: En donde llamas a la funcion `RetornarArticulo`?  Tambien deberias de agregar tu HTML.

Comment: bueno estoy usando un plugin jspanel y bueno donde se encuentra la función también esta la tabla haber lo voy agregar

Comment: Necesito saber como se llenan las filas de la tabla y donde llamas a la funcion.

Comment: Bueno solo uso el la funcion ajax.reload de datatable para ello cuando inicializo datatable alli creo los inputs agrego el codigo en mi pregunta para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Y en donde llamas a la funcion???

Comment: esa función esta dentro de ese mismo script ahora le he asignado la función a otro boton que esta dentro de otro script que se encuentra en el otro formulario

Comment: Intenta mover la funcion al `initComplete` de datatables.  Ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: acabo de probar me sigue devolviendo cero habrá algo que este haciendo mal :(

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final cambie la función de datatable por esta

```
"drawCallback": function (settings) {
        let tbl = this.api();
        var input = $(tbl.rows().nodes()).find('[id^=cantidad]').attr('name');
        console.log(input);
        if (input != 'undefined' && input > 0) {
            $('#FrmOrdendeCompra').bootstrapValidator('addField', "'" + input + "'", {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The phone number is required'
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

según leí eso se ejecuta luego del ajax.reload para un función personalizada que desees hacer aquí la documentación [DrawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)